# app crashes on button press if nothing is in TextEdit

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Im working on a small temperature conversion app with Kotlin where the user enters a the temperature in a TextEdit and presses a button to calculate the conversion then conversion  but when the user does not enter a number in the TextEdit and presses the button to do the conversion the app crashes and restarts

How can I go about fixing this?

```
class f_to_c : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.f_to_c)

        val actionBar = supportActionBar

        val temp = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.temp)
        val calculate = findViewById<Button>(R.id.calculate)

        val tempEntered = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tempEntered)
        val result = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.result)

        val msg1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.msg1)
        val msg2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.msg2)


        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.title = "Fahrenheit To Celsius"
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        }

    calculate.setOnClickListener {
        var x = (temp.getText().toString()).toString().toDouble()
        if (!x.toString().isNullOrEmpty()) {
            if ((x % 1).equals(0.0)) {
                tempEntered.text = x.toInt().toString()
                result.text = ((x-32).toFloat()*5/9).toString()
            } else {
                tempEntered.text = x.toDouble().toString()
                result.text = ((x-32).toFloat()*5/9).toString()
            }
            msg1.text = "Fahrenheit Is"
            msg2.text = "Celsius"
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pls enter a number to convert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use `toDoubleOrNull()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check in the first line of listener if your editText is empty. If it has value then go ahead else do no processing on the data.